# Getting input directly in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, netbeans, user-input

I am new to JAVA. This is what I have to do:
User inputs as many marks as he wants by writing a number and pressing **add button** doing that over and over and all those marks are added in arraylist. After he is done, he presses the **sort button** and all the marks are sorted and displayed.
This is what I have:

```
ArrayList <Integer> marks=new ArrayList();   
 private void addActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                   
    marks.add(Integer.parseInt(marksinput.getText()));
    Collections.addAll(marks);
        }                                   

        private void sortActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    ArrayList <Integer> marks=new ArrayList();
    marks.add(Integer.parseInt(marksinput.getText()));
    Collections.addAll(marks);
    Collections.sort(marks);
    marksoutput.setText(marks + "\n");
    }
```

The problem I am having is it does not display all the numbers I added before. It just displays the last number. Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to push up the `marks` list at class level. Remember, variables created inside a method only have method scope.

```
//Move it outside of method at class level
ArrayList <Integer> marks=new ArrayList();
private void addActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {   
{                                 
//Push the latest value into marks list, it will already contain all   previous entries as we are not re initializing it.     
marks.add(Integer.parseInt(marksinput.getText()));
} 



private void sortActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                            
    Collections.sort(marks);
    marksoutput.setText(marks + "\n");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am getting the same output. And what do you mean by 'Push the latest value into marks list'? Thank you

Comment: Did you change your `sortActionPerformed()` method as per above suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where the events are actually saved; you are adding them to the marks array but that is local to the addActionPerformed method and lost once that is completed.

It is hard to say with just the code you posted but maybe you can try to make marks a global object in your class.

Comment: I made my arraylist global by moving it outside but still nothing

Comment: can you post the entire classs?